# How to get class name for dynamically changing elements using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape from a webpage that changes it's class names and other element attributes dynamically (there is no pattern in the name of the class). I use code in the following format:

```
element_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains (@class, "DkEaL")]')
```

a snippet of the webpage element is:

```
<button aria-label="cats-over-fence" jsaction="pane.rating.moreCats" jstcache="98" class="DkEaL" jsan="7.DkEaL,0.aria-label,0.jsaction">35 reviews</button>
```

Is there any way to detect this element as it changes dynamically without manually inspecting it?

Comment: How about using a CSS selector like `button[jsaction="pane.rating.moreCats"]`?

Comment: I can try using a CSS selector but I'm not sure if the jsaction stays the same or it also changes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If your webelement always contains the word "reviews" and it is the first element with this property in the HTML, then you can target it with the following

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(., "reviews")]')
```

If it is not the first button containing "reviews", then you can do the following

```
position_of_your_button = 5 # for example
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(., "reviews")]')
button = buttons[position_of_your_button]
```

If this is not the case, then you have to rely on the position of the webelement in the HTML, but to help on this you should give us the full HTML code or simply the url of the webpage.

Comment: The position can change if there is "reviews" before that element, I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: @fsaa then give us the full HTML code or simply the url of the webpage, otherwise i cannot help

Comment: A sample/test url would be: 

https://rb.gy/6bj5ne

and:

https://rb.gy/piusdq

Comment: @fsaa In the first link there are two `button` elements containing the pattern `x reviews` where `x` is a number (see here https://i.ibb.co/XzX8SCq/324.png), which one do you want to scrape? In the second link there is no `button` containing the pattern, so what is the element that you want to scrape in this case?

Comment: I'll be scraping both the pages, for details

Comment: @fsaa I didn't ask which page you want to scrape, but which element you want to scrape in each page

Comment: Name, Address and rating and a few comments and total reviews. so in that case it would be the element you identified as well as these things